# Create setup package for obfuscated code for C# Windows Application

Tags: c#, .net, obfuscation, net-reactor

I have used .Net Reactor to obfuscate code. Now how do I create create setup package for the obfuscated code. Or are there any other tool for creating setup package for obfuscated code.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this is a problem.  Why don't you create the setup package *before* obfuscating the assemblies?

Comment: When I create a setup package, the package gets created without the obfuscated assembly. And I want to create the setup with the obfuscated assemly/exe.

Comment: Create the setup project first.  Then obfuscate.  Then re-build the setup project.

Answer (score 1):

I had no problem with BitHelmet Obfuscator. My setup package just uses the obfuscated assemblies in BitHelmet's output folder, instead of project output.
Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the VS included setup project? For that, the obfuscator needs to support MSBuild based obfuscation, so that the obfuscation takes place as part of build process. This way, the obfuscated dlls are available for the setup project.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do with Dotfuscator. Below are the steps.
You need to create Dotfuscator project first, i.e right click on solution->add project->select Dotfuscator as project type. To the project created right click on Input-> map to project output from your actual project. Build the Dotfuscator project. Next add the setup project. Point setup project output to that of Dotfuscator. And now build to create the setup. Now your code is obfuscated.

Now I am looking for a solution to work with .Net Reactor, obfuscation and add the output to setup package.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .NET Reactor VS Add-in in to automatically obfuscate the assemblies. This way your setup package will include the obfuscated files.

The solution is described here: [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64806223/12720992)