# .NET Reactor and InnoSetup

Tags: obfuscation, inno-setup, net-reactor

I have a VS 2010 C# "solution";  It creates an .exe file, and a .pdb file when doing a build in Release mode which I use in the InnoSetup build of the installer.

My app uses several .dll's from other vendors (i.e. WinSCP).  My question is:  do still build the installer using InnoSetup, substituting the new .exe from .NET Reactor for the one created by Visual Studio?  The only thing I want to obfuscate using .NET Reactor is my app, not the other vendors.

(I have looked in Google and SO, and did not find an answer.)

Comment: From the Installer point of view, you have to include all your application needs to run in the target machine, nothing more, nothing less. If the documentation of the mentioned .NET reactor is not clear, you can check yourself by doing the process manually and when you get your program to run on a different machine, you just use the installer to automate what you achieve by hand.

Comment: @jachguate: Please move this to an answer below so I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could directly substitute the exe/dll before you build the installer.

In case you want to automatically protect a VS project file output (exe/dll) before it is packaged into your into you setup you could use the [.NET Reactor Visual Studio Add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64806223/12720992).

Answer (score -1):

Install dotFuscator then you will be able to add its project type in source code as new project. There you can set output files to obfuscate.