# Create Obfuscated Setup in VS2010 Using .Net Reactor

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, obfuscation, net-reactor

I am using .Net Reactor To Obfuscate my project.
In my project I have about 10 dlls.
I want my setup to deploy the obfuscated dlls in client's machine.

I tried putting the code below in **Post-Build** Event at Properties of the setup Porject.

```
"C:\Program Files\Eziriz\.NET Reactor\dotNET_Reactor.exe" -project "E:/s.nrproj"
```

But when i deploy it and try to open the deployed dlls in Reflector, it Opens and show the code.
Where/What am i missing???

Comment: why you don't obfuscate the codes in your machine and put the files for deploying?

Comment: Obfuscate your dlls separately and then check them by Reflector to be sure your obfuscator works.

Comment: yes, if we obfuscate them separately on .Net Reactor's window then it works, but when we try to build setup using these separately obfuscated dlls, Dependency error occurs.

Comment: When you obfuscate your assemblies it is possible that .NET cannot recognize your dependencies automatically. But what kind of dependency error do you have? It cannot find an assembly?

Comment: Also if you want to use previous method, you should use Pre-Build instead of Post-Build. (You shouldn't obfuscate your setup project, do you know this?)

Answer (score 1):

Dot Net Reactor obfuscates exe's and dll's and stores them in a different location. Default is the sub folder Secured where the assemblies were. Be sure to take the secured ones and not the original ones in your deployment scheme !

Answer (score 0):

You should obfuscate your assemblies before building your setup project, therefore you should use your command in Pre-Build instead of Post-Build. When you obfuscate your assemblies it is possible that .NET cannot recognize your required assemblies automatically. I strongly recommend that obfuscate your assemblies separately and then create your setup project (ensure that all of required assemblies are added to your project).

**NOTE**: There is some bugs about creating setup project in VS2010, sometimes closing and opening the visual studio works.

Answer (score 0):

This works on my side:

```
if /I "$(ConfigurationName)" == "Release" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Eziriz\.NET Reactor\dotNET_Reactor.Console.exe" -file "$(TargetPath)" -targetfile "$(TargetPath)" -q
```

and if you want to set config proj then add it like this:

```
-project "$(SolutionDir)obfuscation_settings.nrproj"
```

Given that .net reactor project is placed in solution folder and its name obfuscation_settings.nrproj

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

The Post-build event doesn't work in this case. You can use the .NET Reactor VS Add-in in order to obfuscate the assemblies at the right time. The solution is described here:
[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64806223/12720992)